# When does version in google drive REST API change?

Tags: google-api, drive

The property "version" in [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) changes for a file even when there is no change made to the file or its properties. So why does this happen? What could be the other conditions under which the version changes?

Answer (score 0):

You really should read the documentation that you yourself linked before posting.

> [version](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) long 
> A monotonically increasing version number for the
>   file. This reflects every change made to the file on the server, even
>   those not visible to the requesting user.

Any time the file is changed the version number will be increased.  Even if it is not changed by you but by someone or something else.